# Question about a theorem concerning the continuity of integral functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

If we have 
$$F(t):=\int_V f(t,x)dx$$
where $V$ is some measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ and $x\mapsto f(t,x)$ is a measurable function. Moreover let $F$ be defined for all $t\in U$ a open subset of $\mathbb R$.

Then if $t\mapsto f(t,x)$ is continous for almost all $x$ and we can find an integrable function $g(x)$ such that $|f(t,x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $t\in U$ it follows that $F(t)$ is continous.

I wanted to ask, since continuity is a local property, is it not sufficent to find a bounding function $g(x)$ for every $t$ on some interval $(t+\epsilon,t-\epsilon)$ for an arbitrary small $\epsilon$ ? The idea came up because the proof of the first statement uses dominated convergence to show that $\lim_{s\to t} F(s)=\int_V \lim_{s\to t}f(s,x)dx=\int_Vf(t,x)dx$ and hence this would work for every $t$ on a arbitrary neighborhood of $t$.

I appreciate any replies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the argument would work if the set $V$ is compact so that you can patch together a finite number of smaller intervals.

Comment: Thorben: You are absolutely correct. This is also an important point, in some cases it is only possible to find such a "local" majorant, but no "global" one.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks a lot, I just see that makes certain things much easier!